# Set page size on client side telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have tried a lot but didn't find the way to change page size of telerik grid on client side
Till now I have this on my grid

```
.Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(25, new int[] { 25, 50, 100 })
.Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric | GridPagerStyles.PageSizeDropDown))
```

It works fine but I want to bind page change event with one of my dropdowns.

I didn't find any event that telerik grid's page dropdown call that I can use to call with my dropdown change.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way to do this

```
function pageSizeChanged(pageSize) {
    if (pageSize == '#')
        return true;

    var grid = $('#StudentGrid').data('tGrid');
    grid.pageSize = pageSize;
    grid.rebind();
}
```

This works like a charm! :)

Comment: where you have specified the event to call the pageSizeChanged  javascript function ?

Comment: how this pageSizeChanged function gets the call? could u please add complete code